# Controlling scons environment checking options

Tags: build, scons

I'm trying to build mongodb (open source version 4.2) which uses python and scons for building. The problem relates to scons rather than mongodb.

My build fails very early with `Couldn't find OpenSSL crypto.h header and library`. Verbose details are:

```
file /.../SConstruct,line 3042:
        Configure(confdir = build/scons/opt/sconf_temp)
scons: Configure: Checking for SSLeay_version(0) in C library crypto... 
build/scons/opt/sconf_temp/conftest_d6743137aeb7fb2674cc9632f9989034_0.c <-
  |
  |
  |#include "openssl/crypto.h"
  |
  |int
  |main() {
  |  SSLeay_version(0);
  |return 0;
  |}
  |
gcc -o build/scons/opt/sconf_temp/conftest_d6743137aeb7fb2674cc9632f9989034_0.o -c -std=c11 -ffp-contract=off -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -pthread -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-pch -Werror -O2 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-const-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-exceptions -fstack-protector-strong -fno-builtin-memcmp -fPIE -DNDEBUG -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -D_GNU_SOURCE build/scons/opt/sconf_temp/conftest_d6743137aeb7fb2674cc9632f9989034_0.c
cc1: error: command-line option '-Wno-exceptions' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
scons: Configure: no
```

I'm using Arch Linux which has multiple OpenSSL packages, and the default 3.0 is not compatible with mongodb source. I also have OpenSSL 1.1 and 1.0 installed, and can switch with e.g. `gcc -I/usr/include/openssl-1.1`.

Unfortunately I have not found a way to instruct SConstruct to use this flag in the command lines it generates to check the environment. I have tried `CFLAGS`, `CCFLAGS`, `CPPPATH` both as environment variables and scons command line parameters.

I also tried reverse enginering it, and tracked this to `Conftest` and `TryBuild` but it's not obvious how I can influance theses from the command line, so I'm trying my luck with you guys before going deeper in scons code.

Comment: I am getting the same error.  This error does not look to me like it can't find the headers.  It looks like it is trying to compile a C file  with a flag (specifically -Wno_exceptions) that isn't valid with C.  Normally this would be ignored with a warning, except -Werrors has been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the SConstruct and search for openssl, you'll find this blurb under the logic to detect on macOS

```
            NOTE: Recent versions of macOS no longer ship headers for the system OpenSSL libraries.
            NOTE: Either build without the --ssl flag, or describe how to find OpenSSL.
            NOTE: Set the include path for the OpenSSL headers with the CPPPATH SCons variable.
            NOTE: Set the library path for OpenSSL libraries with the LIBPATH SCons variable.
            NOTE: If you are using HomeBrew, and have installed OpenSSL, this might look like:
            \tscons CPPPATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include LIBPATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib ...
            NOTE: Consult the output of 'brew info openssl' for details on the correct paths."""
```

I'd bet if you did the same but pointed at the proper locations on your system for the openssl libs and header files, you'd be able to build.

(see: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.2.0/SConstruct#L3015 )

Comment: Thanks, I did try `CPPPATH` and though it didn't work at the environment checking stage, but you are right, it does work. I still get the same high level error though, because flags passed to gcc are not compatible with my version but I found a work around